# How to run a C++ program in python as a root?

Tags: boot, scripts, python, root

I want to run a C++ program at boot with root privileges, I could not find how to do it.

```
import subprocess

 def run_c_program();

   subprocess.call("/home/pi..../example")
```

When I run the script from the terminal it works, but how can i do the same thing at boot?

Comment: I believe this question falls under the topic of using Ubuntu specifically.  He's looking for help on the running startup applications.  He showed an example of a script he has written which should work.  But he's trying to figure out how to add it to his ubuntu startup process with the intended behavior.  It would be similar to how to save a LibreOffice document with permission so that other users can edit it.  While the steps for other distributions are similar.  Using those same steps in Ubuntu is commonly accepted questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a program or script to the /etc/rc.local file.  This script is run at boot time.  All the lines in the script are run as root.

If you have a program named /usr/local/bin/myprogram and added this line to the rc.local script it would be run as root.

/etc/rc.local:

```
# By default this script does nothing

/usr/local/bin/myprogram
```